# How to use jQuery UI Tabs on a page with request parameters

Tags: jquery

I have a page, that shows a table when there is no parameter. But if a parameter is passed, it instead shows a form for editing. I'm trying to use jquery tabs here but it loads the whole page with the table into where the tabs content should be.

Html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Edit Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Images</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <strong>Form goes here</strong>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <strong>Edit images here</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot before running `$('#tabs').tabs()`:**
[image: Before running tabs()]

**Screenshot after:**
[image: After running tabs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in MooTools that was included by Joomla. Although I'm not using any mootools functions, it was somehow getting triggered by a "load" event from jQuery. I decided not to use tabs as I couldn't find the solution. But I had this same problem when I was using a modal popup for images. (debugged through Network tab on developer tools and found MooTools being the culprit.) Just remove it and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Too me this sounds more like a backend issue. The server should give you only a partial file instead of the whole site to reduce bandwidth usage. That's not really a jquery issue but an issue of how you handle the request server-side.

Give it some parameter like partial=true or check if it's called via AJAX request and then deliver only the partial file.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when href="#someid", the page should scroll to that element? It should not even load a new page. And the element does exist on the page.

Comment: No, you're absolutely right. Have you set something like baseURL or has the Edit Product button any other URL in the href property? What happens when you click on Images?

Comment: Without running tabs, the page actually redirects to `/products#tabs-2` from `/products?product_id=1`. But after running tabs, it does not redirect. It simply switches the tabs like normal, but like the screenshot.

Comment: The <base> tag is the same as the URL without the parameter.